# Make div remains in same position when reduce browser width?

Tags: html, position, scrollbar, wrapper

http://wthdesign.net/test/html/01-homepage.html

I have an id created call "rightColumn", when I reduce the browser's width it gets push down to the next column, how do I make the id stays in its original position with scroll bar instead?

I understand I can make an outer wrapper to hold off the "leftColumn", "middleColumn" and "rightColumn" but is there any other solution out there other than creating an outer wrapper?

Thanks~

Comment: I can do A B C. With those how can i do  XYZPXGMJDA. Post some code that creates the layout. Else how could we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and it seems to me that your rightColumn div is not inside of the content div like the leftColumn and middleColumn. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the rightColumn

```
overflow:hidden;
```